# Allow drop file upload in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, file-upload

I have a file upload which works great in everything except IE. When i drag a file or picture to the upload area and drop it that file or picture opens and redirects my site. How do i stop this?

The plugin i used is simple and can be found here, they also have a quick snipt to see how to implement it.

http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-For-Drag-Drop-File-Input-Field-ezdz.html

You can see the code on how to implement this file upload in the link above, its pretty much a one liner.

Comment: According to the link you provided I see that this plugin supports IE10+

Comment: @Pavlo i can't get it to work on IE10 or edge. on the drop even IE always tries to open that file and redirects away from my site.

Answer (score 2):

try to prevent default behaviour of drop event: (not tested!)

```
<body ondrop="drop(event)">
```

JS:

```
function drop(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: I tested with an alert, in Chrome the alert fires in IE the page is redirected to the file before an alert fires

Comment: I guess you should handle ondragover event and preventing default behaviour of this event instead. Firstly try `<body ondragover="drop(event)">` Are you still redirected?

Comment: Hey that worked. So i guess i'm half way there now i just need IE to accept the drop. But thanks having been directed away on every drop was very annoying.

Answer (score 1):

If you need lt ie10 support try http://filedropjs.org/. There is no point in reinventing the wheel :).

Comment: Thank you for this, the previous solution did only work in firefox here.